# ASP e caminhos no include

Tags: iis, asp, include

Olá,

Tenho uma aplicação instalada em IIS 8 cujo ficheiro default faz include de outros ficheiros em pastas localizadas antes da directoria do default.asp.
Exemplificando:

o ficheiro default.asp localiza-se em:

```
httpdocs/www/pasta1/pasta2/pasta3.1/pasta4/default.asp
```

e quero que este carregue ficheiros localizados em:

```
httpdocs/www/pasta1/pasta2/pasta3.2/pasta3.2.1/ficheiro.asp
```

No default.asp tenho:

```
<!-- #include file="../../pasta3.2.1/lang.asp"-->
```

contudo surge-me o internal server error do IIS.

Se eu colocar o ficheiro lang.asp na mesma directoria do default.asp, este é carregado.
A ideia é este (lang.asp) ser carregado por outras aplicações em outras directorias.

Conseguem ajudar-me?

Comment: Entretanto foi possível a correcção deste problema. Deixo aqui a resolução para o caso de surgir alguém com a mesma situação.
Foi necessário, na Application Pool do site, nas definições do ASP colocar a True o parâmetro "Enable Parent Paths".
Fiz depois restart à app pool e a aplicação ficou a funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, o uso de "Parent Paths" no IIS é desabilitado.

Você pode habilitar ou desabilitar o uso de "Parent Path" usando o IIS Manager.

Abra o IIS Manager e navegue até seu site ou aplicação que você deseja configurar o "Parent Path" e de dois cliques na opção "ASP"

[image: IIS]

Nas listas de configurações do ASP, configure o "Parent Paths" para true.

[image: IIS]

Segundo a Microsoft, você também pode executar a seguinte linha de comando:
`appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/asp /enableParentPaths:"False" /commit:apphost`

Mas eu nunca o fiz desta maneira, sendo assim recomendo a opção exibida nas imagens.